# Android Studio for Mac doesn't start

Tags: java, macos, android-studio

Android Studio doesn't start.
Please help

android studio 3.5
openjdk version "13" 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I think you need to add more details. What do you want to achieve for example?

Comment: @Ferie what OP wants to achieve is pretty obvious: open Android Studio. What OP needs to do is provide a lot more context and then keep in mind that SO is no tech support forum for people unable to setup their mac / computer.

Comment: For me, in this question, is not clear if the application Android Studio does not start or the program that he wrote does not start...

Comment: @Ferie *"Android Studio doesn't start"* and *"Android Studio for Mac doesn't start"*! It really does not get *any* clearer than that. On the off-chance that OP actually means something entirely different: that is not our problem.

Comment: On that chance, is exactly why I downvoted the question and put the first comment.

Comment: Just ran into this issue. In my case, it was my studio.vmoptions file that was giving me a hard time. Give it a look.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. I can't start Android Studio on my mac.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. Turned out it was because I downloaded the wrong version (I downloaded the Apple version instead of Intel, didn't know my Macbook has an Intel chip)

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are new to StackOverflow so let me give you some advices before trying to answer.

You'll have to provide some more details about your issue so we can help you.

Now let's come to the question:

I understand **Android Studio** won't start on your Mac. 
From my experience there are two possible issues:

1) **Android Studio.app** folder (Apps on Mac are folders) is corrupt, or has some missing files. Try deleting it from **Applications Folder** and copying it again.
If that doesn't solve, try downloading it again, you might have corrupt **dmg** file.

2) **MacOS** is still trying or has failed verifying **Android Studio.app**. Try opening up a terminal which is in **Applications/Utilities/Terminal** and type in:

**`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`**

This command makes sure **MacOS** skips verification for given App, so it should start.

Let us know if you manage to solve

Comment: I tryed 2). I saw this [xattr: /Applications/Android Studio.app: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine]

Comment: When I download android studio , I can start it (but not launch). And when mac restarts , android studio doesn't start